# No output when executing python file from c#

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio

I build a Webscraper in python, which generates the right output when executed. Now I wanted to implement it to a C# project and it doesn´t work. I just don´t get any ouput from it. I tried finding a problem with printin things to labels in different steps but it seems to work fine. My python code:

```
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/AAA")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
soup_find = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"pull-left meta-col"})[0].find("span",{"class":"series-meta-observation-value"}).text
print(soup_find)
```

And my C# Code (in Visual Studio):

```
        private void cmd_scrape_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = @"My\path\to\Webscraper.py";
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"My\path\to\python.exe", fileName)
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        p.Start();
        lbl_Out.Text = "Starting...";
        string Output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        lbl_Out.Text = "Waiting for exit...";
        p.WaitForExit();
        lbl_Out.Text = "Done";
        lbl_Out.Text = Output;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=netframework-4.8) may help

Comment: Unfortunatly it didnt help, I tried to modify my code, but nothing

Comment: As an idea, try adding newline `\r\n` to python's output at the end of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't directly answer to your question because I have no python installed and can't reproduce the problem. But I'll show how to do the same thing completely with C#.

*I assume that the C# project is WinForms.*

Install 2 NuGet packages (in Visual Studio menu Project -> Manage Nuget Packages)

- `HtmlAgilityPack`
- `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack`

First one provides HTML parser, 2nd provides an extension `HtmlNode.QuerySelector`. Query syntax for `QuerySelector` is almost the same as in JavaScript.

After installation add namespaces to the code.

```csharp
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using HtmlDocument = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument; // overrides class name conflict with System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument
using Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack;
```

And whole code of the project

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            label1.Text = "Connecting";
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/AAA", HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                label1.Text = "Receiving data";
                string text = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(text);
                label1.Text = doc.DocumentNode.QuerySelector("div.pull-left.meta-col span.series-meta-observation-value").InnerText;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            label1.Text = "Error";
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\r\n\r\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, I hope you are fine with me using it for my application?

Comment: @Marvlogs You're welcome. Everything on StackOverflow is OK to use it for your application.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the python and C# code, and it works fine and print "2.50". Maybe you can try to add break point to confirm whether the code in `cmd_scrape_Click` has been executed.

[image]

Comment: It has been executed, which I can see by removing the `lbl_Out.Text=Output`, because then it says "Done". There has to be something with the Output Text. I will keep trying, but thanks for the idea!